# Elastic search score documents based on how close numerically a string is

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

Assuming we have documents with the following format in elastic indexed:

```
{
  "street": "Adenauer Allee",
  "number": "119",
  "zipcode": "53113"
}
```

and we have a query like:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "zipcode": {
                            "query": "53113",
                            "fuzziness": "0"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "street": {
                            "query": "Adenauer Allee",
                            "fuzziness": "auto"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "number": {
                            "query": "119"
                        }
                    }
                } 
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's say that our index contains 3 documents
with

```
street: "Adenauer Allee"
zipcode: "53113"
```

and they have different house numbers like:

```
doc1: number: "11"
doc2: number: "120"
doc3: number: "10a"
```

(Notice the "a" in doc3).

The above query will return as a result **doc1** with number "11" (since it's closer alphanumerically).

Desired behavior is to return first the document with the closest numerical value.
In the above scenario this is **doc2** with number "120".

How can I achieve that?

Elastic search info:

```
{
"name": "193a315bccae",
"cluster_name": "demo",
"cluster_uuid": "kg3tZZOyqOgqTbn_elqs_g",
"version": {
"number": "7.5.1",
"build_flavor": "default",
"build_type": "docker",
"build_hash": "3ae9ac9a93c95bd0cdc054951cf95d88e1e18d96",
"build_date": "2019-12-16T22:57:37.835892Z",
"build_snapshot": false,
"lucene_version": "8.3.0",
"minimum_wire_compatibility_version": "6.8.0",
"minimum_index_compatibility_version": "6.0.0-beta1"
},
"tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `script_score`-query allows you to implement your custom scoring logic (see Elasticsearch reference: [Script Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/query-dsl-script-score-query.html#query-dsl-script-score-query)). Rather than implementing your own script, you can also use one of the predefined decay functions for numeric fields, assuming that you "cleaned-up" the street numbers from characters (you can can convert `number` into a multi-field and store the numeric part of it separately, e.g. `number.numeric`)

In previous versions of Elasticsearch you can use the `function_score`-query to implement the same logic (see Elasticsearch reference: [Function Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)).